# Occasional spikes in time taken for comparing String with null in Java

Tags: java, performance, testing, null

I wanted to know if I save time by removing a check for (Object == null) in the beginning of a function. I ran the four following tests:

```
    String test = null;
    String test2 = "Hello";
    String test3 = "ASMDAKLSMDKLÖASDJAKLHRFÖKLASJDKLASMDKLASJDMASKLDMASKLÖDMASKLDMASKLÖMDKLÖASMDKASMDKL";
    int u, v;
    u = 1;
    v = 1;
    long max = 999999999l;
    long time;

    time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        if(test == null) u = v;
    }
    System.out.println("Test 1: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " ms.");

    time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        if(test2 == null) u = v;
    }
    System.out.println("Test 2: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " ms.");

    time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        if(test3 == null) u = v;
    }
    System.out.println("Test 3: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " ms.");

    time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    }
    System.out.println("Test 3: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " ms.");
```

Turns out, most of the time, the difference is within the margin of error. Most of the time, all four functions took about 385 ms to complete, and all were within 2 ms of that, even the one with no comparison.

However, every now and then, perhaps every fourth run, one function took longer than the others. This was ALWAYS test 2, and the time was always around 570 ms.

Any ideas why? I understand as I use the computer there might be performance drops, but it is always in the same test, and the resulting time in that case is within milliseconds of 575.

Just hit me as I was writing this, that time is exactly 1.5 times the original. But why?

Comment: FWIW, I am not able to reproduce with the Oracle JRE 7. The first test is always going to be slower because it takes into consideration class loading, GC spin-up, etc. Also, a good compiler is going to optimize away some of those null checks anyway. Basically, you are going to have to profile the code to determine what is going on, and it is going to be somewhat compiler AND runtime specific. For example, if you make some of the test values (especially "max") final, those tests are going to be much easier to optimizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an effect of some runtime optimization for access variables in loop.
I ran following code on my machine and result was always the same.

```
    String test = null;
    String test2 = "Hello";
    String test3 = "ASMDAKLSMDKLÖASDJAKLHRFÖKLASJDKLASMDKLASJDMASKLDMASKLÖDMASKLDMASKLÖMDKLÖASMDKASMDKL";

    {
        int u = 1;
        int v = 1;
        long max = 999999999l;
        long time;
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            if(test == null) u = v;
        }
        System.out.println("Test 1: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " ms.");
    }

    {
        int u = 1;
        int v = 1;
        long max = 999999999l;
        long time;
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            if(test2 == null) u = v;
        }
        System.out.println("Test 2: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " ms.");
    }

    {
        int u = 1;
        int v = 1;
        long max = 999999999l;
        long time;
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            if(test3 == null) u = v;
        }
        System.out.println("Test 3: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " ms.");
    }

    {
        int u = 1;
        int v = 1;
        long max = 999999999l;
        long time;
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        }
        System.out.println("Test 3: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " ms.");
    }
```

Comment: Alright, seems likely. When I added a fifth loop, it started appearing in the result of the fourth at the same time as the second. Thanks for the reply!